# Hiding an object using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flot

I am trying to hide a vertical bar I have created in a jQuery Flot graph when the mouse is not within the bounds of the grid. I set me horizontal bounds for the grid as such: `horizontalBounds = [leftOffset, plot.width() + leftOffset];`. I then used an if statement to say "if the mouse is within the vertical bounds, do this to the verticalBar.css."

```
if (position.pageX >= horizontalBounds[0] && position.pageX <= horizontalBounds[1]) {
            if (typeof verticalBar !== "undefined" && verticalBar !== null) {
              verticalBar.css({
                transform: "translate(" + position.pageX + "px, 0px)"
              });
            }
```

Below is my css code (which is actually in my javascript file; don't ask...). What do I need to do to hide the verticalBar when the mouse is not within those horizontal bounds? I was thinking I could just add the attribute `visibility: hidden' to the verticalBar.css, but I can't figure out how to do that. Any hints?

```
verticalBar.css({
              backgroundColor: "#F7E4E6",
              width: "1px",
              height: "100%",
              position: "absolute",
              padding: 0,
              margin: 0,
              left: 0,
              transform: "translateX(" + plot.getPlotOffset().left + "px)"
            });
          }
```

Comment: Please tag your post with the appropriate tags - at least the jQuery tag is certainly necessary. I also don't find your question very clear - what's your reason for not using `:hover`? Also, adding `visibility: hidden` works via the .css() function as normal...

Comment: css doesn't have any "vertical" or "horizontal" mouse restrictions. it has "mouseover", which applies to any element, which are always rectangular.

Comment: @MarcB: CSS doesn't have "mouseover", it has `:hover` - and that is by no means always rectangular, but dependant on the bounds of the object.

Comment: @TheThirdMan: yeah... hover. mybad. monday mornings 'n all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so none of those methods seemed to work for me. I ended up discovering that Flot has a crosshair plugin (flot.crosshair). The crosshair can be configured to act only on the x axis/ x coordinate as it tracks the movement of the mouse.  Here is an example of the crosshair tracking in action: [Flot Tracking Example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/tracking/).
Once the plugin was added, I was able to get the desired results; as the "vertical bar" only shows up when the cursor is on the grid. Below is really all you need to do to configure it (other than adding the plugin to the appropriate files). Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
 plot = $.plot(
                placeholder
                data
                grid:
                    clickable: true
                    hoverable: true
                    color: "white"
                    mouseActiveRadius: 1000
                tooltip:
                    show: true
                    content: '%y'

                crosshair:
                    mode: "x"
                    color: "#FFFFFF"
                    lineWidth: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try using "display:none;" in your CSS.

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be displayed when the mouse is within the bounds of the grid. Let's say I was going to add an `else` statement to the 2nd above `if` statement. How would I add `display: none` to the css?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're wanting to hide the bar, you can have something as simple as `display: none`.

If you're wanting to add in some animations, you could use some jQuery functions to control that particular node.

You could also utilize a set of CSS class name swaps to trigger some CSS animations.